# Filepicker.io widget appending to "window.history"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, filepicker.io

The Filepicker.io modal widget (specifically the "IMAGE_SEARCH" service) appends to the `window.history` in the DOM after a search is made. This creates an issue working with [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) when attempting to go back a previous page.

What causes this, and is there any way to prevent it?

[edit] Incorrectly referenced "IMAGE_SEARCH"

Answer (score 0):

What causes this:

Navigation around the modal manipulates `window.location.hash` for compatibility with the window view and a number of other conveniences. Why these changes are affecting the window.history outside the iframe sandbox, I'm not sure.

How to prevent it:

I'm looking into whether we are leaking state somehow, but one easy way to prevent it is to use the `{container: 'window'}` option for filepicker.pick(), so that the dialog is created in a separate window.

Comment: Misread that you are looking into it. But also, a heads up that it occurs with webcam service as well.